# Something like .htaccess in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a directory with lot of files (above 4.000.000 files). All filenames has this same pattern:

```
PREFIX-XXXXXX-YY.ext
```

where

- `XXXXXX` contains letters and digits
- `YY` contains digits
- `ext` is a extension of file (.txt, .jpg)

File structure have 12MB, so listing/searching of this directory takes long time. I divided all content of this directory to subdirectories, depends of filename, precisiously first letter of `XXXXXX` from pattern above.

ie.

- `main_directory/A/PREFIX-AXXXXX-YY.ext`
- `main_directory/B/PREFIX-BXXXXX-YY.ext`
- `main_directory/1/PREFIX-1XXXXX-YY.ext`

Is in Linux easy way to make a rule, when I type in linux command for example

```
test:/home/usr/admin # ls main_directory/PREFIX-AXXXXX-*
```

I will get a list of filenames from main_directory/A/ directory? This rule MUST work only for `main_directory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this at file-system layer, not without creating links and circling back to your original problem. I can think of two easy ways out.

## Take 1: scripting

You could write a short script to rewrite the names for you.

Suppose you had a `rewrite` script that took `PREFIX-AXXXX-*` and outputted `main_directory/A/PREFIX-AXXXX-*`. You could then change your `ls` line to:

```
$ ls `rewrite PREFIX-AXXXXX-*`
```

This can be easily accomplished with `sed`, `awk` or any other on-the-fly text transformation tool.

Shell programs are composable for a reason! :)

## Take 2: embed a faster file-system

You could do away with the restructuring and rewriting names by using a faster file-system, mounted in your main directory. [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) sounds good for this. It should remove your performance concerns without further ado.

This requires a deeper understanding of what's going on to be effective for day-to-day usage, however.

**Edit**: [Here](http://freecode.com/articles/virtual-filesystem-building-a-linux-filesystem-from-an-ordinary-file)'s an article on how to create virtual user-space file-systems.

**Edit 2**: actually no, I don't think `XFS` would cut it. Maybe another file-system, though.